# Reset or Override user agent stylesheet

Tags: google-chrome, css

I am using SVGs, and for some reason, the height is set to 289 px by the user agent stylesheet.

I dont want to define the height, as I will be using many SVGs (like at least 256), and dont want to set different css rules manually for each of them by using `!important`.

So how do I adjust the user stylesheet (using Chrome) or reset the height field for SVGs!, so that it is not defined?

example SVG HTML:  (SVG height is 25 px, yet the svg Bounding box renders to 289)

```
<div id="measure<%= measure.cid %>" class="measure">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="250" height="25" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:2; fill:lightgray;" />
    <div id="<%= beatHolder %>">
    </div>
  </svg> 
</div>
```

[image: css]
[image: css2]

When trying `Alex W`'s answer, I get this:
[image]

Comment: Do you have a link to the site?

Comment: [github](https://github.com/VT-CHCI/SoundOfFractions/tree/movingBeatsView) its a rails/backbone project, and devise is on, so to get you the page, you would either have to fork it yourself

Comment: Are you looking to set the height for the `svg` once like they will all have the same height or are they all going to have different heights?

Comment: Would `height:auto !important` work if you applied it to all of your SVGs?

Comment: multiple SVGs with most of them having different heights.

Comment: Hmm I really need to be able to play with it to figure it out.

Comment: working on getting it up...

Comment: @MitchellLayzell message me, check profile for email....

Comment: @chrisFrisina you're e-mail isn't there..

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just add the rule to your stylesheet?

```
<style type="text/css">
 ...
svg { height: auto !important; }
</style>
```

You want to put that rule at the very bottom of the style tags to make sure it takes priority.

Also, in your code example it seems you are setting the `rect` to be 25 pixels, but not the actual `<svg>` element.

Comment: the svg bounding box should be exactly the width and height of all elements within the svg.  This is what I have always been used to....   When I added this, the computed style shows `height at 369px`, with an expandable arrow, that when clicked, shows `svg - auto !important  main.css:252`.  See pic above

Answer (score 1):

Okay so after playing with your example, I've come up with an answer for you. When using `svg` its `computed style height` is set from its parent element, so with that being said you would have to place your `svg` inside a div that has a `width` and `height` so I made a quick little example of how this would be used, so lets say we want to put a `svg` as a logo and then one for a banner or something we would accomplish this by doing your `svg` like this,

**CSS**

```
.logo {
    width: 250px;
    height: 27px;
}
.navigation {
    width: 960px;
    height: 54px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="logo">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <rect width="250" height="25" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="lightgray" />
  </svg> 
</div>
<div class="navigation">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <rect width="960" height="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="lightgray" />
  </svg> 
</div>
```

Comment: try email now, its posted,   i can send you the link....    this is fascinating, im just trying to figure out how the parent divs computed heights are getting calculated, cause they are not in the css...

Comment: The parent div is getting there height from the CSS style I wrote, which will change the computed heights for the svg to match its parent so if your svg is 25 in height make your div around it 27px high, the reason the divs height will be 27 and not 25 is because  your svg has an outline of 2 on it.